# How to set locale for localized routing specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, localization

I have set up localized routes as per [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

```
#routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  #my resources
end

#application_controller.rb
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

But when running routing specs, no default locale is being set, causing errors such as

```
Failure/Error: it { expect(edit_user_path(1)).to eq("/users/1/edit") }

ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
  No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil, :locale=>1} missing required keys: [:id]
```

After much Googling, I have found little on best practices for testing localized routes. Can anyone point me towards good articles?

Specifically, I want to know:

1. How can I set a default locale for routing specs, such that the
   above example sets the ID key correctly.
2. Is there an easy way to test that routes exist for all permitted locales, and do not exist for non-allowed locales. Or would this require adding a loop to each of the routing spec files?

e.g.,

```
['en','fr'].each do |locale|
  expect(edit_user_path(1, locale: locale)).to eq("/#{locale}/users/1/edit")
end
```